Issues with Installing ng2-charts and chart.js in Angular Standalone Component
I'm currently working on an Angular project where I want to implement charts using ng2-charts and chart.js. However, I'm facing some dependency resolution issues. Here’s a summary of the situation:
Current Setup:
Angular Version: [Your Angular Version, e.g., Angular 15]
chart.js Version: 4.4.5
ng2-charts Version: 6.0.1
Steps Taken:
I initially installed chart.js and ng2-charts using the following commands:
npm install chart.js npm install ng2-charts --save
After installation, I encountered the following error:
Module '"ng2-charts"' has no exported member 'NgChartsModule'.ts(2305)
I tried downgrading chart.js to version 3.0.0 to match the ng2-charts@3.0.0 dependency but encountered this error:
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
Current Project Structure:
The component using the charts is defined as a standalone component:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard',
    standalone: true,
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
    imports: [NgChartsModule],
})
export class DashboardComponent {
    // Component logic...
}


Questions:
What are the correct versions of ng2-charts and chart.js that I should use together?
How can I resolve the dependency issues while ensuring compatibility?
Is there a specific way to set up charts in a standalone component in Angular?
I expected the ng2-charts library to work with chart.js without any issues, allowing me to easily create and display charts in my Angular application. I hoped that downgrading the versions would resolve any compatibility issues.
What Actually Resulted:
Instead of successfully implementing the charts, I encountered multiple errors that prevented me from progressing with my project. The initial import error and subsequent dependency resolution error created a blocker, making it difficult to integrate chart functionality into my application.

When using the latest version of ng2-charts the module has been removed and has switched over to standalone imports.
It is documented in their npm page -> ng2charts - npm
First install the dependencies.
npm install chart.js npm install ng2-charts --save

Then add the providers required by ng2-charts in your main.ts or the providers array of app.module.ts.
main.ts
import { provideCharts, withDefaultRegisterables } from 'ng2-charts';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [provideCharts(withDefaultRegisterables())],
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));

app.module.ts
import { provideCharts, withDefaultRegisterables } from 'ng2-charts';

@NgModule({
  providers: [provideCharts(withDefaultRegisterables())],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}

Then you can just import the directive in the imports array of either a standalone component or module and start using it.
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [BaseChartDirective],
})
export class MyComponent {}

The link shared has the clear cut explanation on installation and usage.
